# how to check input value has only numbers in angular?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation

I want to compare a value of a field centerCode which is entered by a user into an input field. Then I want to check if it is a number and show the appropriate alert accordingly. I am not able to compare  the value or variable number with the variable code .

```
 var numbers =/^[0-9]+$/;
 var code = $scope.Nuser.centerCode;
 alert(code);
 if(code.val(numbers))
 {
     alert(code.val(numbers));
 }
 else
 {
     alert("enter numbers only");
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to use an input number instead of an input field ? Could be way easier

Comment: I agree wit @Apédémak, it would be much easier to use an input number. If you really wanted to, however, you could loop over the string checking if it contains numbers 0-9.

Comment: Instead of code.val(numbers) try new RegExp(numbers).test(code)

Comment: Instead of checking you can restrict the user to give appropriate value. Check this low size plugin, which will help you solve the issue.. https://github.com/Jeevanandanj/angular-input-decimal-separator

Answer (score 3):

You're along the right lines. Numbers needs to be a Regex though, and you need to use the `test` function to check the input against it. The `test` function will return true if the string is all numbers, or false if there is anything else in it.

```
var numbers = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/);
var code = $scope.Nuser.centerCode;

if(numbers.test(code))
{
    alert('code is numbers');
}
else
{
    alert("enter numbers only");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use ng-pattern instead . Something like following :

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" ng-model="inputNumber"/>
```

It will only allow the user to enter the number.

You can use `angular.isNumber` to check if the entered value is a number or not. Try something like the following :

```
if(angular.isNumber($scope.Nuser.centerCode)){
   alert('Center Code is a number');
}else {
   alert('Center Code is not a number');
}
```

Hope this will do the trick.

Comment: thanks vaibhav but in my case the user should be able to enter values and i want to show an alert for the case if he has not entered numbers , nyways thanks for the answer but the requirement is lil bit different here

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert string to number and test is it's `NaN` (Not a Number)

```
isNaN(+$scope.Nuser.centerCode)
```

if it's `false` it means your centerCode contain only numbers

Answer (score 0):

**try this hope this is what you are looking for**

```
 if(angular.isNumber(value))
       { 
        //your code here 
       }
```